# Cambiar formato fecha

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, datetime

Me gustaría que el formato de la fecha fuera años mes y día y luego la hora pero , ahora mismo me sale día mes año y la hora.

```
$fecha = new Date().toLocaleString().replace(",","").replace(/:.. /," ").replace("/","-").replace("/","-");
```

Me devuelve 8-01-2020 8:43:00 y yo quiero 2020-01-08 8:43:00 para poder almacenarlo en el formato correcto en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Cual es tu formato de fecha original? Para ver si se pueden evitar tantos replace...

Comment: 8/1/2020 8:49:04 ese es el formato sin los replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma

```js
  Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
    var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
    return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
  }
  var d = new Date,
  dformat = [d.getFullYear(),
           (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
           d.getDate().padLeft()].join('-') +' ' +
          [d.getHours().padLeft(),
           d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
           d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
  console.log(dformat);
```

[Fuente original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632346/how-to-format-a-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-format-in-javascript)